# How to override minus sign

Tags: swift

let's say I have

```
struct M {
    let x: Int
}
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
let m = M(x: 1)

let minusM = -m

print(minusM) // -1
```

Any way of doing that?

Comment: Do you have a valid use case for this or is the question just out of curiosity?  Moreover, the downvote might have happened since your question is quite vague, especially for a self answered Q&A.

Comment: Not sure how it can be considered vague, it's a pretty straight forward question, how to create the minus operator. I even added code as in `-m`, `m` being the struct `M`. And yes, there is a valid use case, but it isn't relevant for the answer.

Comment: Well, without a valid use case it doesn't really make a lot of sense to define the prefix minus operator for a struct.

Comment: Like I said, there is a valid use case, I just can't disclose it here.

Comment: Well, if you can't disclose the use case, your Q&A isn't really helpful for anyone else here on SO... If you made your question more generic into something like "how to override unary operators for custom structs", it could be useful even without a specific use case, but such a generic question, "how to override minus sign" doesn't really hold any value without a valid use case.

Comment: @DávidPásztor feel free to edit the title, but you just said the same thing as I did. "how to override unary operators for custom structs" == "how to override minus sign".

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz note that if you would like it to print `"-1"` you would need to make your string conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and implement description property `var description: String` returning a string description of the x value

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for creating a minus sign operator for a struct `M` is as follows:

```
prefix func - (_ m: M) -> M {
    return M(x: -m.x)
}
```

Comment: Again, why the downvote? I just tested and it works.

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. Please explain what the solution you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I edited the answer, let me know if it's a little better. But in any case, what it does is pretty obvious from the question (and not particularly relevant, it could be doing something completely different). What I was looking for with the question was only the correct syntax to create the minus sign.